# Java Interfaces with same variables name is extended by another variable?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I have interfaces A & B with a variable of same name but different value.

```
 Interface A {

    public static final int a = 50;

    public void fun();

    }



Interface B {

public static final int a = 60;

public void fun();

}
```

Another interface C extends A & B

```
Interface C extends A, B {    

public void fun();

}
```

A class D implements interface C

```
Class D implements C {



public void fun() {

/* Some code */
}
```

}

What happens if i use D.a ?
which one of the static variable a is inherited by the class D.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  You could have answered your own question.

Comment: The field name is ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. When you do this, the reference to constant `a` becomes ambiguous, requiring you to specify which one you want explicitly:

```
public int fun() {
    return a; // Get an error below
}
```

> error: reference to "a" is ambiguous

```
public int fun() {
    return B.a; // Works fine
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ambiguous to the compiler and will cause an error when used, something like the field is ambiguous. Since the field is `static`, you can resolve against the class name, e.g. `A.a` or `B.a`.